# How to save multiple file from URLs in one zip using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, zip

I am scrapping the files from URLs using beautiful soup, and then want to store those files in a single zip using Python. Below is my code snippet for one URL.

```
fz = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\data\\data.zip', 'w')


response = urllib2.urlopen(url/file_name.txt)
file = open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\data\\filename.txt','w')
file.write(response.read())
file.close()

fz.write('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\data\\filename.txt',compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) fz.close()
```

This snippet is not working for me can any one please help me on this. getting below error:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
>   'C:\Users\ADMIN\data\filename.txt'

but file is present in this location.

Comment: Seems to be working here.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
fz.writestr("file_name", url.read())
```

as many times as you need. I.e. one writestr() per file. Select the zip's mode (deflated) at the opening of the new ZIP.

So, you do not need to save file to disk, then pack it. Just get the html's name and  the content and feed them to writestr(). ZIP gets '/' as a path separator. Therefore you use something like: "/some_dir/some_subdir/index.html" for subdirectories or "/index.html" to put a file into root.